# How can I parse this list of comma separated values

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a list of comma-separated users and their permissions, where some users have up to 8 permissions:

```
user_a, permission_1
user_b, permission_1, permission_2
user_c, permission_1, permission_2, permission_3
```

I need my output to be a list of comma-separated users and permissions, where every user and permission pair are on a separate line:

```
user_a, permission_1
user_b, permission_1
user_b, permission_2
user_c, permission_1
user_c, permission_2
user_c, permission_3
```

My python code below using the csv module is currently not working:

```
import csv

with open('user_list.csv') as user_list:
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(user_list)
    ul = []
    for row in dict_reader:
        ul.append(row)

with open('output.txt','w') as output:
    fields = 'USER','PERM1','PERM2','PERM3','PERM4',
    'PERM5','PERM6','PERM7','PERM8'
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fields)
    csv.DictWriter.writeheader(dict_writer)
    for i in ul:
        dict_writer.writerow(i)
```

It's giving me the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cops_ul_parse.py", line 15, in <module>
    dict_writer.writerow(i)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 148, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 144, in _dict_to_list
    ", ".join(wrong_fields))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: PERM8, PERM7, PERM6, PERM5
```

Any idea why this isn't working? Or, is there a better way to accomplish my desired output? Maybe a regex would work better?

Comment: Note that making a list, then appending each row can just be replaced with `ul = list(dict_reader)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
fields = 'USER','PERM1','PERM2','PERM3','PERM4',
'PERM5','PERM6','PERM7','PERM8'
```

Your code is doing `fields = 'USER','PERM1','PERM2','PERM3','PERM4',` (remember tuples and lists can have trailing commas after the last item), and then making another tuple (`'PERM5','PERM6','PERM7','PERM8'`) and doing nothing with it.

Then, when you make the `csv.DictWriter`, it only has the fields from the first tuple - hence the error you are getting.

The solution is simple: use brackets around your tuple, which then gives you implied line continuation:

```
fields = ('USER','PERM1','PERM2','PERM3','PERM4',
          'PERM5','PERM6','PERM7','PERM8')
```

You can use a backslash to escape the line break too, but brackets are much nicer to read.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the traceback! However, I realize now that my code doesn't solve my problem. I'm still ending up with users and their permissions on one line, when I need each user and permission pair on new lines.

Comment: @JamesNicholson Well, give it another go now that's fixed, and if you have more problems, feel free to post another question :).

Answer (score 0):

```
for perm in listOfPermissions:
    user, perms = perm.split(',', 1)
    for p in perms:
        print "%s, %s" %(user, p)
```

To write this to a file:

```
with open('path/to/file', 'w') as outfile:
    for perm in listOfPermissions:
        user, perms = perm.split(',', 1)
        for p in perms:
            outfile.write("%s, %s\n" %(user, p))
```

Comment: -1 - There is no reason to reinvent the wheel - the asker did the right thing by using the `csv` module in the first place.

Comment: @Lattyware: true. But I didn't have much time to post a `csv`esque answer and opted for a quick reply instead